# Get records of the current day when loading index With Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel

it turns out that everything works for me. But I have seen that I have poor performance since I get all the logs. I would like to obtain only those of the current day. How could i do it

public function index(Request $request)
{
if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

```
    $buscar = $request->buscar;
    $criterio = $request->criterio;
    
    if ($buscar==''){
        $ventas = Venta::join('personas','ventas.idcliente','=','personas.id')
        ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
        ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_comprobante',
        'ventas.created_at','ventas.efectivo','ventas.efectivo1','ventas.tarjeta','ventas.vales','ventas.cambio','ventas.total',
        'ventas.estado','personas.nombre','users.usuario')
        ->where('ventas.estado','=','Venta Registrada')
        ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc');
       
    }
```

Comment: Logs? are there any logs in your question, and please describe schema at least where we could find the current day as you want filtered by

Comment: if ($buscar==''){
            $ventas = Venta::join('personas','ventas.idcliente','=','personas.id')
            ->join('users','ventas.idusuario','=','users.id')
            ->select('ventas.id','ventas.tipo_comprobante','ventas.fecha_hora',
            'ventas.created_at','ventas.efectivo','ventas.efectivo1','ventas.tarjeta','ventas.vales','ventas.cambio','ventas.total',
            'ventas.estado','personas.nombre','users.usuario')
            ->where('ventas.fecha_hora','=','2020-08-04')
            ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc')

Comment: I want it to take the current day instead of 2020-08-04

Comment: You can use `Carbon` library to get today's date in this format : `where('ventas.fecha_hora','=',Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Carbon` library to get today's date in this format :

```
where('ventas.fecha_hora','=',Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))`
```

For your Code:

```
        $ventas = Venta::join('personas', 'ventas.idcliente', '=', 'personas.id')
            ->join('users', 'ventas.idusuario', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('ventas.id', 'ventas.tipo_comprobante', 'ventas.created_at', 'ventas.efectivo', 'ventas.efectivo1', 'ventas.tarjeta', 'ventas.vales', 'ventas.cambio', 'ventas.total', 'ventas.estado', 'personas.nombre', 'users.usuario')
            ->where('ventas.estado', '=', 'Venta Registrada')
            ->where('ventas.fecha_hora', '=', Carbon::today()->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->orderBy('ventas.id', 'desc');
```

Comment: I would use where date instead of this approach, so instead whereDate('ventas.fecha_hora',Carbon::today()), just syntaxic sugar but prettier none the less :)

Comment: @mrhn Ooh, that sweet taste of Laravel syntax - sorry totally unrelated, just had to say it 